# How to use 'phpmailer_init' SMTP settings only on certain 'wp_mail' actions?

Tags: wp-mail, smtp

Is there a conditional check I can run for `phpmailer_init` or a `wp_mail` parameter that let's me apply my custom `phpmailer_init` SMTP settings only on specific `wp_mail` actions or does `phpmailer_init` always run sitewide?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`phpmailer_init` will always fire for every `wp_mail()` call - however, you can hook/unhook it conditionally like so:

```
function wpse_224496_phpmailer_init( $phpmailer ) {
    // SMTP setup

    // Always remove self at the end
    remove_action( 'phpmailer_init', __function__ );
}

function wpse_224496_wp_mail( $mail ) {
    // Example: only SMTP for emails addressed to foo@example.com
    if ( $mail['to'] === 'foo@example.com' )
        add_action( 'phpmailer_init', 'wpse_224496_phpmailer_init' );

    // Example: only SMTP for subject "Foo"
    if ( $mail['subject'] === 'Foo' )
        add_action( 'phpmailer_init', 'wpse_224496_phpmailer_init' );

    // Other properties
    $mail['message'];
    $mail['headers']; // Could be string or array
    $mail['attachments']; // Could be string or array

    return $mail;
}

add_filter( 'wp_mail', 'wpse_224496_wp_mail' );
```

Comment: Your code pointed me in the right direction, thank you. I also had to add a `foreach` loop for the $headers array, searching for a match via `strpos`, as my SMTP condition depends on the "From" email address.

Comment: Then you should give code here. Otherwise your answer should be removed and added as a comment to the relevant answer